# Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Component)", although Provider and context are passed

Tags: redux, react-redux

When using Redux in a React app, many other questions solve the problem of `Could not find "store" in the context of...` by reminding that one should wrap the container component in a provider, or the root component, or pass a specific context as an option to `connect`. I'm doing all of this and it only works when I wrap a container component alone... while I would like the provider to wrap the root component. What is the issue?

**versions**

```
react: 16.13.1
redux: 4.0.5
react-redux: 7.2.0
```

**index.jsx**

```js
const store = createStore(reducer, state);
const context = React.createContext(undefined);
render(
    <Provider store={store} context={context}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

**ContainerComponent.jsx** rendered somewhere inside the `App` component.

```js
export const ContainerComponent = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
    null,
    { context }
)(MyComponent);
```

**error**

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in the context 
of "Connect(MyComponent)". Either wrap the root component
in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider
to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer
to Connect(MyComponent) in connect options.
```

=> It's all done though!

Answer (score 0):

The custom context parameters are only intended for very rare use cases.  You shouldn't use it normally.

Remove that code.

Comment: I added them because it also fails without unfortunately.